# Python - What time is it in Turkey?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran when it was noon in turkey..this is what I got:

```
2017-12-22 20:11:46.038218+03:00

import pytz
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

utc_now = datetime.now()
utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
aware_date = utc.localize(utc_now)
turkey = timezone('Europe/Istanbul')
now_turkey = aware_date.astimezone(turkey)
```

Why did I get 20:11:46?

Comment: datetime.now() doesn't return UTC now, it returns the time in your current timezone. Use datetime.utcnow()

Answer (score 4):

Because the base time is wrong, just change `utc_now = datetime.now()` to `utc_now = datetime.utcnow()` and then it works.

As @RemcoGerlich has said, you should use `utcnow` to get UTC.

Whole code:

```
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
aware_date = utc.localize(utc_now)
turkey = timezone('Europe/Istanbul')
now_turkey = aware_date.astimezone(turkey)
```